# Event triggering but not updating textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have a asp.net application that has webform1.asp.cs and a custom class class1. class1 is instantiated in webform1.asp.cs. I am raising a custom event event1 from class1. This event1 is consumed in webform1.asp.cs. I have a asp.net text box control (multiline). Inside consuming event1 code in webform1.asp.cs, I write some text to asp.net text box. The event gets raised but the text box does not show the text. However, when I write to Debug, it displays the text. What is going on?

//Event code in class1:

```
public delegate void StatusChange(object sender, EventHelper args);
public class EventHelper : EventArgs
{
    public string message;
}

EventHelper e1 = new EventHelper();
            e1.message = "some text";
           OnStatusChange(this, e1);
```

//In webform1.asp.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1 cs = new Class1();
    cs.OnStatusChange +=cs_OnStatusChange;
}

void cs_OnStatusChange(object sender, EventHelper e)
{
    TextBox1.Text += e.message;
}
```

Comment: Where is your code being called in the page lifecycle? Is it after page init or page load?

Comment: One thing to note is that your Class1 cs variable is scoped within the page_load method. Without seeing anymore code than you have posted, it is hard to tell what is happening. Where in class 1 is the OnStatusChange fired, and where is the event triggered from within the web form?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I realized asp.net webcontrols do not get re-rendered when an event occurs unless you do a post back. That means when the event was raised from another class, although the event handler was working and seemingly the textbox was populated in the code but it was not getting rendered on the UI. I eventually created a WPF browser application.